# GitHub Action for reading JSON file

Tags: terraform, github-actions

I would like to write a GH action that uses JSON data as a parameter.

The plan is to save the Terraform output as a JSON file in one step and access it in the sequential step.

```
name: Test and Terraform
on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ main ]
jobs:
  Unit-Tests:
...
  Terraform:
    runs-on: ubuntu-18.04
    needs: [ Unit-Tests, S3-Sync ]
    steps:
...
      - name: Terraform Apply
        if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/main' && github.event_name == 'push'
        run: |
          cd terraform
          terraform apply -auto-approve
          terraform output --json > output.json

      - name: Set Terraform Output
        id: output
        if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/main' && github.event_name == 'push'
        run: |
          content=`cat ./terraform/output.json`
          # the following lines are only required for multi line json
          content="${content//'%'/'%25'}"
          content="${content//$'\n'/'%0A'}"
          content="${content//$'\r'/'%0D'}"
          # end of optional handling for multi line json
          echo "::set-output name=terraform::$content"

      - name: Gatsby Cloud Sync
        if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/main' && github.event_name == 'push'
        run: |
          echo "${{fromJson(steps.output.outputs.terraform)}}"
```

The current error I get with this is that the final step is formatted improperly.

> The template is not valid. .github/workflows/main.yml (Line: 154, Col: 14): Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: c. Path '', line 1, position 1.

How is the last step, `Gatsby Cloud Sync`, formatted incorrectly?

Comment: Why do you have to write to and read from a variable? You can access `output.json` directly in the Gatsby step, no?

Comment: I'm writing a separate GH Action that should take the JSON data as an input. Is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: I obviously don't know any specifics, but as long as the step using that action is in the same job as the step that produces the output, you could use the filesystem instead of passing around the whole JSON.

Comment: Ha, I've bumped into a related problem and found [this post](https://github.community/t/set-output-truncates-multiline-strings/16852) in the GitHub community - I guess that's where your `content` escaping comes from. I've added another answer to that thread using `jq` and `fromJSON`.

Comment: So you're saying that using the file's path would be better than processing the file's data? I still can't get that final echo to work.

Comment: Well, if you use a JSON file in the filesystem, you don't have to take care of any escaping and JSON (de-)serializing at all, so it would be simpler.